# ñ to Ñ string php

Tags: php, regex

I've searched but still stumped

How do I convert a string with ñ to have the ñ in uppercase too?

e.g.

```
"Nuñez"
```

to

```
"NUÑEZ"
```

`mb_strtoupper` is not working due to no english.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take time to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @PaulCrovella that won't work

Comment: So, it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051286/php-mb-strtoupper-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to play with encoding.

```
$content = 'Nuñez';

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
if(!mb_check_encoding($content, 'UTF-8')
OR !($content === mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32'))) {

$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8'); 
}

// NUÑEZ
echo mb_convert_case($content, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
```

via [PHP: mb_strtoupper not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051286/php-mb-strtoupper-not-working)